# Schedule a zenity message on linux

Tags: linux, bash, zenity

I want to create a simple reminder on linux at a certain time everyday. I am using `crontab` to schedule running the reminder script, while in the script I am using `zenity` to display a simple dialog box with a question.

In more details, I have the following script `reminder.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --question --text="question?"
```

Then, using `crontab -e`, I add the following task to run every single minute (just for testing):

```
* * * * * /path/to/reminder.sh
```

But the dialog box doesn't appear. I added some other commands to the script and I confirmed that the script runs every minute, but the dialog box still doesn't appear!

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find the solution. When I did `echo` of the `$DISPLAY` in the same script, it has nothing in it. So, I've set it to my machine display. But this didn't work till I added `xhost +` to the script.

The final script would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
xhost +
/user/bin/zenity --question --text="question?" --display="myMachine:0.0"
```