# Zenity not working in python script with crontab

Tags: python, bash, zenity

I have a python script in which I have used Zenity to display some notification. The code snippet is as follows:

```
if message_list:
    pretty_print(message_list)
    os.system("/usr/bin/zenity --notification --text='You have unread messages'")
```

When I run this script normally, everything works fine i.e. dialog box appears and message gets displayed. But when I schedule this script in crontab nothing appears. Any solution to this?

Comment: Maybe cron isn't allowed to execute on your X11 session? Try forcing to run as currently logged user.

Comment: @Michał I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414086/schedule-a-zenity-message-on-linux?rq=1 . But how to use it in python script?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sane way to run interactive commands from `cron`.  There is no guarantee that there is a user, there is no guarantee that there is a single user, there is no guarantee that the user(s) who are on want to, or are even able to, interact with your software; some of them may be pseudo-users or remote on expensive metered Internet access or just idle or whatever.

The usual solution is a server/client architecture where whatever runs from `cron` makes its results available via some IPC mechanism, and users who want the results run a client from within their X11 session (or shell, or what have you).

Answer (score 0):

Create a script `info.sh` (remember to grant it execute rights):

```
#!/bin/bash
xhost +
/usr/bin/zenity --notification --text='You have unread messages'
```

And in your script:

```
if message_list:
    pretty_print(message_list)
    os.system("./info.sh")
```

That's if you want to use the solution you mentioned.